# __callStatic not being called

Tags: php, magic-methods

Not sure why but Its not even hitting the `var_dump()` that I have. Lets look at how I have it implemented.

```
<?php

namespace ImageUploader\Controllers;

class ApplicationController implements \Lib\Controller\BaseController {
    ....

    public function beforeAction($actionName = null, $actionArgs = null){}

    public function afterAction($actionName = null, $actionArgs = null){}

    public static function __callStatic($name, $args) {
        var_dump('hello?'); exit;
        if (method_exists($this, $name)) {
            $this->beforeAction($name, $args);
            $action = call_user_func(array($this, $name), $args);
            $this->afterAction($name, $args);
            return $action;
        }
    }
}
```

As we can see I want to do something before and after an action is called, regardless if you implemented the method or not. But that `var_dump` is never reached.

This class is extended in:

```
<?php

namespace ImageUploader\Controllers;

use \Freya\Factory\Pattern;

class DashboardController extends ApplicationController  {

    public function beforeAction($actionName = null, $actionArgs = null) {
        var_dump($actionName, $actionArgs); exit;
    }

    public static function indexAction($params = null) {
      Pattern::create('\Freya\Templates\Builder')->renderView(
          'dash/home',
          array(
              'flash' => new \Freya\Flash\Flash(),
              'template' => Pattern::create('\Freya\Templates\Builder')
          )
      );
    }

    ....

}
```

Now when I do: `DashboardController::indexAction();` it should exit ... unless I am missing something. If that's the case - what is it?

even the `var_dump` in the `before_action(...)` that's implemented is never reached (obvi' because of the first one, but if I take out the first one the second is never reach.)

Comment: `__callStatic` is called only when a static method *does not* exist - as `indexAction` is defined, it is executed without bothering `__callStatic()`. Also see: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.callstatic

Comment: Oh crap, I should have read that a bit closer. Is there a way to do what I am trying to do? Is there a different implementation I should be looking at?

Comment: I will write something in a "real" answer, where code is more readable :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`__callStatic` is called only when a static method *does not* exist - as `indexAction` actually is defined, it is executed without bothering `__callStatic()`. ([Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.callstatic))

An approach to achieve what you are trying to do could be by wrapping your controller inside a decorator:

```
class ExtendedApplicationController
{
    /**
     * @var \Lib\Controller\BaseController
     */
    protected $controller;

    function __construct(\Lib\Controller\BaseController $controller) {
       $this->controller = $controller;
    }

    function __callStatic($name, $args) {
        if (method_exists($this->controller, 'beforeAction')) {
            call_user_func_array(array($this->controller, 'beforeAction'), $name, $args);
        }

        call_user_func_array(array($this->controller, $name), $args);

        if (method_exists($this->controller, 'afterAction')) {
            call_user_func_array(array($this->controller, 'afterAction'), $name, $args);
        }
    }
}
```

and then, in your code, you could do:

```
$controller = new ExtendedApplicationController(new DashboardController());
$controller::indexAction();
```

I have to warn you that I didn't test this approach while I was writing it, but I hope it gives you an idea!